# iOS: Swift: Combine Accelerometer and Attitude data for comparable results

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, gesture, core-motion

## Idea

My idea is to write a little application for my iOS-Device to record a motion after start recording by touching an UIButton and save the data from the accelerometer for this motion. After the recording, I can save this data to use it in the finished Application to detect this motion again.

So, what I'm looking for is a way to compare two NSMutableArrays, each as a set of motion data, and want to check if the current NSMutableArray is the same motion as the recorded one.

## Problems

To realize this idea, I found three problems, which I can't solve myself:

1. How to compare two NSMutableArrays and get e.g. an index-level of the similarity or a percentage e.g. 97.32% equivalent.
2. What if the user makes the motion in different speeds? E.g. slowly or fast.
3. <s>The last problem: How to handle different device-orientations? Is there a way to calculate the data from the accelerometer to a neutral level in any orientation? I think I have a solution approach for this last problem, but don't know how to bring this to code: We have the attitude data for pitch, roll and yaw. Maybe we can calculate with these values the neutral data for the accelerometer?</s>

## Code

At this moment, I only have the code to get the data from the accelerometer and the attitude data, both from the MotionManager. I played multiple hours with my code and searched a lot on Google, but can't find the right way...

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

var x:Float = 0.0
var y:Float = 0.0
var z:Float = 0.0
var roll:Float = 0.0
var pitch:Float = 0.0
var yaw:Float = 0.0

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1
            motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1
       }

       @IBAction func startRecording() {
        accelerometerData = NSMutableArray()
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xMagneticNorthZVertical, to:
            OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {
                (deviceMotion, error) -> Void in
                let attitude = deviceMotion?.attitude
                let roll = self.degrees(radians: attitude!.roll)
                let pitch = self.degrees(radians: attitude!.pitch)
                let yaw = self.degrees(radians: attitude!.yaw)

                self.roll = Float(roll)
                self.pitch = Float(pitch)
                self.yaw = Float(yaw)

                let accX = deviceMotion?.userAcceleration.x
                let accY = deviceMotion?.userAcceleration.y
                let accZ = deviceMotion?.userAcceleration.z
                self.x = Float(accX!)
                self.y = Float(accY!)
                self.z = Float(accZ!)
        })
    }
}
```

## Update

I will update this question, when I know more.

**Problem 2: Solution:**
With the Attribute `CMAttitudeReferenceFrame.xMagneticNorthZVertical` for the `motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates`-Method you can neutralize all sensors data to a defined orientation. You can access the accelerometer-data here too. I've updated the code above, too.